Is there a generic 'Open' for OpenXML for word and excel files?
I am accessing the CustomFilePropertiesPart of Word and Excel files in order to retrieve and update a custom property.
Thats OK except there is messy duplicated code because each file type apparently needs its own open statement. eg
var officeFile = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, false)
var officeFile = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false)

Once open both file types seem to use the same
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.CustomFilePropertiesPart? customProps = officeFile.CustomFilePropertiesPart;

So my question is:- Is there a common (parent?) open command that could be used for all Office file types using OpenXML?
Seeing I dont want to access the actual data of the file type just the metadata, But I do want to update that metadata
Thanks for your advice
JC

As far as i know it doesn´t exist, but if you create it i think it will not cost you a lot, if you will always return the class CustomFilePropertiesPart, you will just need use the right class to open the file for each office application to access the property CustomFilePropertiesPart.

seergius96 I came to the same conclusion.  It doesn't look beautiful but I can live with it.  Its a few more lines than just the open because the open returns different types eg {DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument} or {DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument} so both extracting the CustomFilePropertiesPart and creating it if its not there yet all have to be file type specific.
